# 'fontFamily' does not exist in type 'ThemeOptions' in MUI theming

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to learn some react basics and ofcourse MUI by building a dashboard.

Here is my App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import './styles/styles.scss';
import { createTheme,ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
const muiTheme = createTheme({
  fontFamily: 'NotoSans-Bold'

});
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CssBaseline enableColorScheme />
    <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

But I am getting a an error at the createTheme constant

```
Argument of type '{ fontFamily: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThemeOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fontFamily' does not exist in type 'ThemeOptions'
```

[image]

What did I missed or did wrong..

Answer (score 0):

The MUI suggested way of doing this is by setting the font family at the `typography` level of the theme *(not in the root of theme theme)*.

From the [MUI.com docs on Font Family](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/#font-family):

> ### Font family
>
> You can change the font family with the
> `theme.typography.fontFamily` property.
>
> For instance, this example uses the system font instead of the default
> Roboto font:
>
> ```
> const theme = createTheme({
>   typography: {
>     fontFamily: [
>       '-apple-system',
>       'BlinkMacSystemFont',
>       '"Segoe UI"',
>       'Roboto',
>       '"Helvetica Neue"',
>       'Arial',
>       'sans-serif',
>       '"Apple Color Emoji"',
>       '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
>       '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
>     ].join(','),
>   },
> });
> ```

**Note:** You will still need to add the references to the externally-hosted fonts (in your case `NotoSans-Bold`) in the page, stylesheets, etc. or you can [import the self-hosted fonts if you have an appropriate plugin/loader configured](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/#font-family).

*You could also do this manually (for any non-MUI controlled content) by defining a style on your body tag, but I think that's outside of scope for this question.*